# Is $z^z$ continuous everywhere in $\mathbb C$ except at 0?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is $z^z$ continuous everywhere in $\mathbb C$ except at 0? further more is the discontinuity at 0 removable?

update : the problem in this question is about multivaluedness of $z^z$, can we separate the multivalues into separate cases such that eac case is continous everwhere except for 0 and then remove it?

Comment: $z^z$ is not defined as a single-valued function on $\mathbb C-\{0\}$.

Comment: @πr8 , updated the question.

Comment: Did you try to choose a continuous branch of $\log$ and define $g(z)=e^{z\log(z)}$

Comment: @EclipseSun , yes, can vlues of multivalued functions be separated in a way that they form continous cases?

Comment: @E.Girgin , it is dispesring the multivalues in such a way that they end up within a continous map, so we end up with inifinitely many continous maps that contain all the values. Some points may end up in more than one map, but all the maps are continous and all the points are in one or maps.

Comment: I can't talk for the general multivalued functions, but Log can be. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm about the branches. I'm not sure how these branches act under your example either.